# Get session id from ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, session, asihttprequest, session-cookies

I need to retrieve a session id after authenticating against a server. In the completion block I try to NSLog all the device's cookies:

```
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  NSLog(@"cookies: %@", storage.cookies);
```

But the result is an empty array. The request.responseHeaders also do not contain any cookies. How do I get the session id?